# How to use special characters in jquery array

Tags: jquery, arrays, angularjs

I would like to use special characters in jquery array. Not sure how I achieve that.

$scope.categories = ['Red', 'White', 'Rose', 'Sparkling'];

and want to use

$scope.categories = ['Red', 'White', 'Rosé', 'Sparkling'];

Any one help me please

Comment: What error does it gives?

Comment: What is wrong with the second line? you can use `é` so long as the document is saved in Utf8

Comment: It just not display that option when page load. Only display Red, White, Sparkling

Comment: Document display in UTF8 but not sure angular just not display that option when page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/b3hzc62c/)

you can use special characters

`&aacute;` = á

`&eacute;` = é

you can find all the characters here http://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html